# Excel VBA Save text as '.fcf' file extension

Tags: vba, excel

I've got this code to save text from an excel sheet into a .txt file.

I need to adapt this to save the `.txt` file as a `.fcf`

currently I work around this by saving the text file then manually renaming it `test.fcf`. Is it possible to rename this in VBA? Or save directly to `.fcf`?

```
 Sub SaveColumn(sheetName As String, columnName As String, fileName As String)

      Dim cell
      Dim fso
      Dim file

      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, True)
      For Each cell In Sheets(sheetName).Columns(columnName).Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
          file.WriteLine cell.Value
        End If
      Next
      file.Close

      Set file = Nothing
      Set fso = Nothing
    End Sub

To call it...

    SaveColumn "Output to fcf.1", "A", "P:\4_Calcs\02. Flag Mapping\test_.txt"
```

Comment: @pnuts .fcf in this case is a 'flag change file' specific to InfoWorks ICM. When I rename a text file manually to test.fcf it can then be read by InfoWorks ICM it works to make changes in InfoWorks ICM models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to change the filename in the call?

```
SaveColumn "Output to fcf.1", "A", "P:\4_Calcs\02. Flag Mapping\test_.fcf"
```

Comment: I Had but because of a typo it hadn't worked. Nice simple solution. Cheers!